# Proving that if $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix that $A^2=0 \implies A=0$ with $0$ being the null $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

As the title suggests, I need to find a proof to this statement. I honestly have no real clue how to semi-formally prove this. I can see why it's true and I get the concept, I just don't know where to start with this proof.
Maybe something with linear independence or something? A hint in the right direction would be great!

Comment: Yet it's false.  Consider the matrix $\;\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Well that was unexpected (and easy). Thanks lol

Comment: When you'll learn Jordan reduction, you'll see there are plenty of  (non-zero)  nilpotent matrices.